# Android Facebook login not being processed

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments, facebook-android-sdk

I'm using the latest Facebook Android SDK to authenticate my users, and I'm running into this issue.

I have a root activity set up, with a custom ActivityResult handler system (basically, fragments can register and remove ActivityResultHandlers for specific results, this way handling the result of inter-activity requests within a fragment). I've expanded this with the Facebook CallbackManager, the way it is described in the SDK documentation:

In my activity, I have this:

```
@Override
void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    [...]
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);

   FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
   facebookCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, ActivityResultHandler> entry : activityResultHandlers.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getKey() == requestCode)
            entry.getValue().onActivityResultCustom(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    facebookCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

And in my fragment, I do this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    [...]
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getFacebookCallbackManager(), 
        new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() { [...] }
    );
}
```

Then I call the LoginManager to begin authentication once a button is pressed (I'm using custom graphics, so FacebookLoginButton is out of question unfortunately).

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("email","user_friends","public_profile"));
```

Now, this part works fine, I can see in the debugger that the `facebookCallbackManager.onActivityResult()` method is called. However, stepping inside, I see that the LoginManager is registered for a specific response code (let's say, 64206), while the SDK returns with a totally different request code (129742), and thus, the LoginManager callback is not handled.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

> Move this portion. You need to init `Facebook SDK` before `setContentView`.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity);
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```

> To this

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
setContentView(R.layout.activity);
```

Comment: Does not help. The callback is still not being processed at all.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was pretty simple - move the whole processing into the Fragment itself, and only do the SDK initialization in the main Activity.